# VirtualBox Install doesn't start on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox

My server is a HP Proliant box. I have a fresh install of Ubuntu:

```
cli@proliant:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
cli@proliant:~$ uname -m
x86_64
```

I have tried downloading and installing   Ubuntu 16.04 ("Xenial")   AMD64 from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

When I click on the Install button as show in the screenshot[image], it seems to start the install process for about two seconds then stops.

Is there any log I can check to see if errors are being encountered during the install process?

Any other suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: One easy way to gain some insight to the process would be to open a terminal window, change to the directory that you have downloaded VirtualBox into, and enter the command `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.2_5.2.4-119785~Debian~stretch_amd64.deb` - this will run the installation program in the terminal window, and allow you to see any error messages generated.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. I get this error: sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.2_5.2.4-119785~Debian~stretch_amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing archive virtualbox-5.2_5.2.4-119785~Debian~stretch_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-5.2_5.2.4-119785~Debian~stretch_amd64.deb 
.  The file does exist in that directory so I'm not sure what archive it is referring to. Thanks

Comment: Try entering `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox` and then pressing the "tab" key to get autocompletion just in case there's a spelling error.  You should also check the checksums of your downloaded file to ensure that there was not corruption during the download process.

Comment: You cannot install from BOTH a downloaded deb and the Software Center. You mush choose one and stick to it. If you change your mind, you must completely remove and clean up one before starting to install the other.

Comment: @jazzmine -- the package name he gave is for Debian not Ubuntu; and you didn't download the file. I've experienced problems with software center, try installing from command line `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.2`